# Google Data Studio connector authenticate at third party

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I'm building a Google Data Studio connector to a third party source, Siteimprove. Siteimprove has an api which requires [Basic Access Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

I've setup the authentication for [username and token](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/auth) (I've also tried username and password) in my google apps script, with all the required functions based on the documentation

-edit- as requested the full code for these functions

```
/**
 * Returns the Auth Type of this connector.
 * @return {object} The Auth type.
 */
function getAuthType() {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  return cc.newAuthTypeResponse()
    .setAuthType(cc.AuthType.USER_TOKEN)
    .setHelpUrl('http://developer.siteimprove.com/v1/get-access/')
    .build();
}

/**
 * Resets the auth service.
 */
function resetAuth() {
  var user_tokenProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  user_tokenProperties.deleteProperty('dscc.username');
  user_tokenProperties.deleteProperty('dscc.password');
}

/**
 * Returns true if the auth service has access.
 * @return {boolean} True if the auth service has access.
 */
function isAuthValid() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var userName = userProperties.getProperty('dscc.username');
  var token = userProperties.getProperty('dscc.token');
  // This assumes you have a validateCredentials function that
  // can validate if the userName and token are correct.
  return validateCredentials(userName, token);
}

/**
 * Sets the credentials.
 * @param {Request} request The set credentials request.
 * @return {object} An object with an errorCode.
 */
function setCredentials(request) {
  var creds = request.userToken;
  var username = creds.username;
  var token = creds.token;

  // Optional
  // Check if the provided username and token are valid through a
  // call to your service. You would have to have a `checkForValidCreds`
  // function defined for this to work.
  var validCreds = validateCredentials(username, token);
  if (!validCreds) {
    return {
      errorCode: 'INVALID_CREDENTIALS'
    };
  }
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.setProperty('dscc.username', username);
  userProperties.setProperty('dscc.token', token);
  return {
    errorCode: 'NONE'
  };
}

function validateCredentials(userName,token){

  var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(userName + ':' + token)
  };

  var params = {
    "method":"GET",
    "headers":headers
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.siteimprove.com/v2/", params);
  return response;
  console.log(response);
}
```

And the manifest file

```
{
  "dataStudio": {
    "name": "Connector for Siteimprove",
    "company": "<company name>",
    "logoUrl": "<company logo url>",
    "addonUrl": "",
    "supportUrl": "",
    "description": "This connector can be used to show basic data from Siteimprove"
  }
}
```

When I run the script I get a prompt for credentials, but this is a prompt to connect with a google account [image: connect with a google account]

But I need a way to provide credentials for a third party service.
If I use my google account I get a 401 response from the Siteimprove API, so that seems to work as expected.

Any clues how I would get a prompt to provide credentials for a third party service?

Comment: I don't have a connector configuration page? There is no 'connector' item in the 'edit' menu.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/use#using_head_deployment

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm doing. That'll show this [window](https://imgur.com/a/MDU9Nmm). And when I click 'authorise' I get the pop up window from my original post.

Comment: You need to show all 4 functions code and the manifest file.

Comment: See my edits in the original post

Comment: Try adding a authType in the manifest https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/manifest#authtype

Comment: Same result. I only get an authentication window for a google account and not to authorize a connection for a third party.

Comment: I think you also need `getConfig()` get credentials and add them to properties service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/**
* Returns the Auth Type of this connector.
* @return {object} The Auth type.
*/
function getAuthType() {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  return cc.newAuthTypeResponse()
    .setAuthType(cc.AuthType.USER_PASS)
    .setHelpUrl('http://developer.siteimprove.com/v1/get-access/')
    .build();
}

/**
* Resets the auth service.
*/
function resetAuth() {
  var user_tokenProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  user_tokenProperties.deleteProperty('dscc.username');
  user_tokenProperties.deleteProperty('dscc.password');
}

/**
* Returns true if the auth service has access.
* @return {boolean} True if the auth service has access.
*/
function isAuthValid() {
  const usernameAndPassword = loadCurrentUsernameAndPassword();
  return usernameAndPassword.username && usernameAndPassword.password && validateCredentials(usernameAndPassword.username, usernameAndPassword.password)
};

function loadCurrentUsernameAndPassword() {
  const properties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  return {
    username: properties.getProperty('dscc.username'),
    password: properties.getProperty('dscc.password')
  }
};

function setCredentials(request) {
  var isCredentialsValid = validateCredentials(request.userPass.username, request.userPass.password);
  if (!isCredentialsValid) {
    return {
      errorCode: "INVALID_CREDENTIALS"
    };
  } else {
    storeUsernameAndPassword(request.userPass.username, request.userPass.password);
    return {
      errorCode: "NONE"
    };
  }
};

function validateCredentials(username, password) {
  var rawResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.siteimprove.com/v2', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ':' + password)
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    });

    return rawResponse.getResponseCode() === 200;
  }

  function storeUsernameAndPassword(username, password) {
    PropertiesService
      .getUserProperties()
      .setProperty('dscc.username', username)
      .setProperty('dscc.password', password);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Data Studio will always prompt first for Google Authorization, based on your script's scopes, and then for additional configuration based on your `getAuthType()` function. Since your `getAuthType()` function is `USER_TOKEN`, after authorizing with google, you will have an additional prompt to authorize with those credentials.

[The 4th step](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-connectors/#3) of the codelab outlines the flow of a connector, so you can see what functions are called when.

You also want to make sure that, at a minimum, you have defined `getAuthType()`, `getData()`, `getSchema()`, and `getConfig()`. Since you're using an auth type of `USER_TOKEN`, there are additional methods you must defined as outlined in [Authentication](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/auth)

Comment: Yesterday I was thinking about this and realized this was probably the case. Thanks for pointing this out, because now I know in which direction to search!

Yes I already have defined those functions.

I'll work on my code and will check back if I got it running!

Comment: @JeroenSwets did you ever get this running? I'm also interested in connecting Siteimprove to data studio but have limited app script experience.

Comment: Yes I did! Men it has been a long time, I'll check my code to see what I did exactly and get back to you